# How to sync all branches of two repositories (one in github and one in gitlab) preventing merge conflicts?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Repository X.git is in gitlab with all development artifacts and respective branches
I create Y.git in github using the following approach
In a common server I do a mirror of gitlab

```
git clone --mirror http://gitlabserverdomain/user/X.git
cd X.git
git remote add githubrepoalias https://githubserverdomain/Y.git
git push -f --tags githubrepoalias refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
```

Now I want to enable users to use either repositories for sometime and would like to sync either commits

These commits should not cause merge conflicts.

How do I do achieve the objective?

Comment: You can't do this. The basic premise is that you want magic to happen

Answer (score 2):

I see no way to prevent conflicts between changes done in GitHub and other changes done in GitLab.  Try using hooks on the servers directly to minimize it.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible :)

You just need to to somehow:

- define git fetch-ing both-ways
- make sync interval as short as possible (e.g. using web-hooks to trigger sync as soon as there is a new commit)

I've just tested with GitLab mirroring functionality: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring.html

I've defined **both** Push and Pull rules pointing to a GitHub repo, and it worked - changes are synchronised both ways.